# Create a RESTlet that can access Server Script Log record type

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Our company isn't satisfied with the tools NetSuite gives you to access script logs for a number of reasons. So I wrote a function that searches the '**scriptexecutionlog**' record type, which works fine in the debugger when I am logged in as admin. So I plopped it into a RESTlet, and hit my endpoint, but authenticated as a non-admin, and it always returns no results. I'm assuming this is because only admins have access to the '**scriptexecutionlog**' record type. (Exact same code, so it's not like a typo or anything. I'm positive on that part)

So my first thought was to just create a saved search and check the '**Run Unrestricted**' checkbox. This would allow me to use '***search.load***' with the new saved search id, from within a RESTlet that is being called by a non-admin user. That's precisely what the '**Run Unrestricted**' checkbox is for, yet it doesn't work. If I load that search in my RESTlet, it again returns no results.

So my next choice was to create a new Access Token, and select '**Administrator**' as the role, but apparently you can't do that. '**Administrator**' isn't one of the available options. So I thought I'd create a new role that had access to the '**scriptexecutionlog**' record type, but for the life of me I can't find a permission that allows that.

So I'm stuck. It seems like a RESTlet is unable to query the '**scriptexecutionlog**' record, simply because that requires administrator privileges that can't be added to other roles, and you can't add the Administrator role to User Access Tokens. It's a catch 22.

To sum up, I think if any of these questions can be answered, I'd be good:

- Is there a permission setting for accessing the **scriptexecutionlog** record type? If so, where?
- Is there a way to select '**Administrator**' as the **Role** when creating an Access Token?
- Is there a way to create a saved search that searches on the '**scriptexecutionlog**' record type, that can be loaded from code not being run as admin, so it actually returns results? (in other words, make the '**Run Unrestricted**' checkbox work like it's supposed to)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am able to access script execution logs via a RESTlet call. You can control the access your RESTlet has by controlling the role that you use for your access token.

I have included a screenshot below of the permissions I have granted to my role that is able to access the script logs. The important line is the one that says "SuiteScript" with the access level set to "View". If I remove that line, then I get an INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION error when performing the script notes search.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was actually able to get this working a couple days ago and actually forgot I had posted this.  You're right, it was a permission that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

To create a token for your Administrator role: Home > Settings portlet > Manage Access Tokens.